# Not dead yet! Repairing damaged external links

Tags: support, feature-request

It seems sqlblog.com is now sqlblog.org <sup>**1.**</sup>. One effect of this is to break outgoing links from dba.se.

In the past, I've tried to be a good netizen <sup>[3](https://dba.stackexchange.com/revisions/163904/2),[4](https://dba.stackexchange.com/revisions/148435/2),[5](https://dba.stackexchange.com/revisions/49680/7),[6](https://dba.stackexchange.com/revisions/16386/20)</sup> and edit posts with dead links to an appropriate new home or archive copy (god bless the wayback machine - RIP MS Connect). Sadly in [this case](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/35486/edit), I'm not even able to submit the suggested edit (`.com -> .org`) unless I spam in filler characters to meet the minimum edit length.

> In general - these outgoing links were helpful at the time and still can lead to useful additional relevant information. **Is there a general solution for finding and repairing damaged links across the network?**

I have in mind [the Community-bot going about and hoovering up http `->` https redirects for SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292738/does-the-community-user-only-edit-http-to-https), but I'm not aware of any community-supported solution for arbitrary pattern updates.

#### ...although...

...as I dig into my own revision history for examples... I did notice [this interesting edit history](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/16386/revisions) - so... is that a generally supported solution? If so, how does the general (low-rep) community make suggestions to it?

---

<sup>**1.** as of like like... well... earlier this year  way to stay up to date, self...</sup>

<sup>N.B. this is not an isolated problem: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/extended_events/2010/03/17/extended-blogs-now-cross-posting-to-sqlblog-com/</sup>

Comment: The revision history in your penultimate link shows a sqlblog.com link having been replaced with a Wayback Machine link. I took the [original link](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/08/15/temporary-tables-in-stored-procedures.aspx), replaced .com with .org and tried opening it like that, and what do you think? [It didn't work](http://sqlblog.org/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/08/15/temporary-tables-in-stored-procedures.aspx). So fixing all those links might not be as easy as just replacing the TLD.

Comment: Just to clarify something, sqlblog.com did not become sqlblog.org.  sqlblog.org is actually just Aaron Bertrand's blog.  See [Same old content, brand new home](https://sqlblog.org/2018/01/18/same-old-content-brand-new-home).  Which is why the example from @AndriyM doesn't work (that's Paul White's post, and thus was not migrated to Aaron's blog at sqlblog.org).

Answer (score 7):

It is always awkward when links break (though as of today sqlblog.com is back up).

Aaron has [relocated his content](https://sqlblog.org/2018/01/18/same-old-content-brand-new-home) from sqlblog.com to [sqlblog.org](https://sqlblog.org/).

Nick Craver offered to help Aaron [automate the process of updating links](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1061968684049154048).

[image: tweet]

I imagine the Community updates noted in the question came out of that process.

I have relocated my own sqlblog.com content to https://sql.kiwi

#### General advice

If you come across posts with broken links and are able to fix them, please do so. If there is *really nothing else* that could be improved in the post and you come up against the minimum edit length restriction, **flag the post for a moderator**. We are happy to take care of such things, but please include all the information we need to make the edit in your custom flag description. Or post in [The Heap](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap--consultancy-) to get someone with full edit  privileges to make that change for you.